# Hardcoding C++ shader interop code

Tags: c++, directx9

When writing code that interacts with multiple shaders, is it best practice to hard code the use of each effect? I wrote a couple of hard-coded loops and then noticed that I accidentally ended the pass of the wrong shader, and this has me concerned that instead, I should be writing some sort of Shader class that generically executes a shader. Is this the right way to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it would be more scalable in the long run to write a system could wrap and handle what your shaders need for you.

There are several ways to do this, such as having a "Shader" class like you mentioned that inspects the underlying D3D Effect object for semantic [annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Add_Information_to_Effect_Parameters_with_Annotations) that let your wrapper class determine things like which kinds of vertex or texture input are required, begins and ends all the appropriate classes, et cetera.